# How to set up a new session with a default page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am improving a live website for a client but got stuck on a requirement. Currently when a users forget their password they get sent an email with their encrypted password. They can then use that to log in on the site. The password would remain permanent unless the users go to the change password page (changepassword.php).

What the client wants is to have users directed to the change password page straight away if they are using an encrypted password, instead of the default member page (subjects.php).

For the MYSQL users table I created a new column (temp_password) which would only hold a value of 1 or NULL. The column's value would get updated to 1 when the forgot password request is received. So the new session (directing users to changepassword.php) would only start if the user email and password are matched to a value of 1 in temp_password.

The problem I am having is I cannot wrap my head around how the default session works or how I would need to set this up. I do know that I would need to make the changes to the parts in the two PHP source files below (`user.class.php` and `logincheck.php`).
 I would appreciate any ideas / help.

```
user.class.php
//Check entered login and password. Called From : index.php
function logincheck($dataarray)
{
    $email_id = $dataarray['email_id'];
    $password = $dataarray['password'];     

    $query  = "select id, email_id, password, phone, user_type, active ";
    $query .= "from users ";
    $query .= "where email_id= '".$email_id."' and password = '".$password."' "; 

    $rs = $this->conn->query($query) or die("SQL ERROR ".$this->conn->error);  //returns single row 
    $row = $rs->fetch_array() ;

    if((trim($row['email_id']) == $email_id) && (trim($row['password']) == $password))
    {                                    
        $this->retmsg['error'] = false; 
        //used to set in session 
        $this->retmsg['user_id'] = $row['id'] ;          
        $this->retmsg['email_id'] = $row['email_id']  ;         
    }
    else 
    {            
          $this->retmsg['error'] = true;
          $this->retmsg['msg'] = 'Invalid Login or Password';
    } 
    return($this->retmsg) ; 
}


logincheck.php
//Used to check login user name and password, called from index.php 
if($identifier == 'logincheck') 
{
    $user = new user($appcon) ;
    $email_id = trim($data[1]) ;
    $password_text = trim($data[2]) ; 
    $remember = $data[3]  ; 

    //store request variables in local variables
    $userarray = array() ;
    $userarray['email_id'] = trim($data[1]) ;
    $userarray['password'] = trim(md5($data[2])) ; 
    $userarray['password_text'] = trim($data[2])  ; 
    $userarray['remember'] = $data[3]  ; 

    $retarr = $user->logincheck($userarray) ;

    if(!isset($_SESSION['USER_ID']))
    {
        $_SESSION['USER_ID'] = $retarr['user_id'] ;          
        $_SESSION['EMAIL_ID'] = $retarr['email_id']  ;    
        //$_SESSION['USER_TYPE'] = $retarr['user_type']  ;  
        //$_SESSION['ACTIVE'] = $retarr['active'] ;   
    }
    if(!isset($_SESSION['REDIRECT_TO']))
        $_SESSION['REDIRECT_TO'] = 'subjects.php' ;                  
    $retarr['redirect_to'] =  $_SESSION['REDIRECT_TO'];

    //if remember me checked set cookie for 100 days
    if($remember=='remember'){
        setcookie("cookname", $email_id, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
        setcookie("cookpass", $password_text, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");    
    }
    else{
        setcookie("cookname", '', time()-60*60*24*100, "/");
        setcookie("cookpass", '', time()-60*60*24*100, "/");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Wait, are you telling that passwords are stored *plain* in database? That's a big no-no. Passwords must be encrypted, better would be with a strong algorithm like bcrypt

Comment: No, the passwords are encrypted

Comment: You create an unique hash. Store that in the users table. In the email you sent you include a link e.g. `new_password.php?h=<HASH>` and with the provided hash in the url you know which user wants to reset their password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saving a value in the database and then doing all the work behind the scenes you could just provide the link to change password page in the email that has the temp password.

Control the expiration date of the password in the database.  So, no new fields in the database and limited new code.

Comment: Thanks could you tell me how this can be done in MySQL? I'm trying password_expired to set the time of expiration but it's not working.       "update users set password_expired='1', password='$reset_password' where email_id = '$email_id' "

Comment: Sorry I have been out of the country for a little bit on the late response here. Just create a field in your user table or password table or where you have the password stored in your database that accounts for a date/time field, call it pw_creationDate and another field pw_expirationDate.  In your code you can either check current date vs expiration date or do the math on the creation date.  For example if creation day is more than 90 days ago flag it and redirect to password/user page.  Or send the email...